# How to make the nested if still looping thru until

Tags: python, nested, nested-if

```
listup = [{'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 1}, {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 2}, {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 3}, {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 4}]
listdown = [{'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 1}, {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 3}, {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 2}, {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 4}]
```

I try to make the `listup` to keep on looping until it meet the same index with `listdown` which ultimately finish pop the `listup`. I did use nested `if` but the loop exit after nexted `if`.

```
if len(listup) !=0:
for up in listup:
    if (listup[0]['index'] != listdown[0]['index']):
        print('1 >>', listup[0]) #for debug purpose
        print('2 >>', listdown[0]) #for debug purpose
        print('seen down earlier than it supposed to')
        print(False)
        if listup[0]['index'] == listdown[1]['index']:
            print('11 >>', listup[0]) #for debug purpose
            print('22 >>', listdown[1]) #for debug purpose
            listdown.pop(0)
            listup.pop(0)
            print('---',True) #for debug purpose
        continue  # HOW TO MAKE THIS STILL RUNNING UNTIL LISTUP IS EMPTY
    else:
        print('1 >>', listup[0]) #for debug purpose
        print('2 >>', listdown[0]) #for debug purpose
        listdown.pop(0)
        listup.pop(0)
        print(True) #for debug purpose
else:
    print('listup empty - finished')
```

this is the output

```
1 >> {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 1}
2 >> {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 1}
True
1 >> {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 2}
2 >> {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 3}
seen down earlier than it supposed to
False
11 >> {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 2}
22 >> {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 2}
--- True
```

I want the code still looping thru the `listup` until the `listup` is empty so that after returning `---True` it still keep on returning the other `print` until the `listup` is empty

*** The code supposed to check between two lists of dictionary, `listup` and  `listdown` for which for each listup dictionary will have their own pair with listdown - same address and same index. Also, the order of `listdown` need to follow the order of `listup`; as you can see the order of dict in `listup` follow the order of their index **1,2,3,4** and the order of dict in `listdown` should be **1,2,3,4** but their original order is **1,3,2,4**.  Hence, the first `if` statement return **'seen down earlier than it supposed to'** and nested `if` to continue check the second dict of `listup` until it meet their pair in `listdown`. This is where the problem arise when the third dict of `listup` doesnt being check as the code stop when print **'--- True'**

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: You shouldn't modify a list that you're looping over.

Comment: Is there any way for me to loop through? as i need to modify (pop) the  `listup`

Comment: Indentation of `continue` is it?

Comment: Indentation of the first `if` statement. Everything else should be indented from it.

Comment: You don't need `continue`. There's nothing to skip over before starting the  next iteration.

Comment: Maybe what you want is `while len(listup) > 0:`

Comment: I can't figure out what this code is supposed to do. Please edit the question to explain it.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, My apologies. I already edit the question. Hope you can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not really clear, but if you simply want to check which items in two list have identical index key and otherwise print whether the item in the second list is "too early" or "too late":

```
for a,b in zip(listup, listdown):
    if b['index'] > a['index']:
        print(f"{b['index']} in b seen too early")
    elif b['index'] < a['index']:
        print(f"{b['index']} in b seen too late")
    else:
        print('True')
```

output:

```
True
3 in b seen too early
2 in b seen too late
True
```